# Ionic - How to record audio and upload it to server on android device?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
import {File,IWriteOptions} from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';

curr_playing_file: MediaObject;
constructor(public _zone: NgZone,
          public databaseService: DatabaseService,
          public socketService: SocketService,
          public params:NavParams,
          private platform:Platform,              
          public viewCtrl:ViewController,
          private media:Media,
          private transfer:FileTransfer,
          private file:File) {  

}
start() 
{
    this.curr_playing_file = this.createAudioFile('audio1.amr');
    this.curr_playing_file.startRecord();   
}
end()
{
     this.curr_playing_file.stopRecord();  
     this.curr_playing_file.release();  
     console.log('released');     


     //SET NAME
     var name = this.getRandomStr();   //get random string

    let option: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey:'file',
        mimeType:'audio/amr',
        httpMethod:'POST',
        fileName:name
    }

   const fileTransfer:FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();


    fileTransfer.upload(this.curfilename, encodeURI(localStorage.getItem('GlobalIP')+"/upload"),option).then((result)=>
    {
        this.sendAudio(name);
        alert('success');
    }
    ).catch(error=>{
        console.log('error');
    });

}

createAudioFile(filename): MediaObject {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {  //ios
        console.log(filename.replace(/^file:\/\//, ''));
        return this.media.create(filename.replace(/^file:\/\//, ''));
    } else {  // android
        return this.media.create(filename);
    } 
}
```

This code works on IOS but does not work on android.
I get the following error message:

> 09-11 19:27:26.313 14361-14505/com.ionicframework.exampleproject223738
>   E/FileTransfer:
>   {"code":1,"source":"audio3.amr","target":"http://183.207.183.247:8080/upload","http_status":200,"exception":"/audio3.amr
>   (No such file or directory)"} java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /audio3.amr (No such file or directory)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:99)
>   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openForRead(CordovaResourceApi.java:249)
>   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openForRead(CordovaResourceApi.java:232)
>   at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:419)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  curr_playing_file: MediaObject;
  recStart:boolean;
  pressed()
      {
        console.log('Longpress');
         //voiceNum INCREASE
         var nItem = localStorage.getItem('recordvoiceNum');
         var numstr = 0;
         if(nItem == null){
             numstr = 1;
         }
         else{
             var numstr = parseInt(nItem,10)            
             numstr = numstr + 1;
         }
          //Create media file
         this.curfilename = 'audio' + numstr + '.3gp';
         this.curr_playing_file = this.createAudioFile(this.curfilename);
         localStorage.setItem('recordvoiceNum', numstr.toString());
         try {
                 console.log('start Recording');
                  if(this.recStart == false){
                    this.curr_playing_file.startRecord();
                    this.recStart = true;
                  }
         }catch(e)
         {
           console.log('record error');
           console.log(e.message);
         }




      }


      released()
      {

        setTimeout(() => {
          try{
            console.log('stop recording');         
            //stop recording 

              this.curr_playing_file.stopRecord(); 
              this.curr_playing_file.release();
              console.log('released');     

              var name = this.getRandomStr();

              let option: FileUploadOptions = {
                fileKey:'file',
                mimeType:'audio/3gp',
                httpMethod:'POST',
                fileName:'audiochat#'+name
              }

              const fileTransfer:FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

              console.log('filename'+this.curfilename);

              fileTransfer.upload(this.file.externalRootDirectory+this.curfilename, encodeURI(localStorage.getItem('GlobalIP')+"/upload"),option).then((result)=>
              {

                 this.sendAudio(name);
                 this.recStart = false;

                }
             ).catch(error=>{
               console.log('uploaderror');
               console.log(error.message);
               this.recStart = false;           
              }); 

          }
          catch(error)
          {
            console.log('stoperror');
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }, 500); 

      }
```